# read /proc/net/xt_qtaguid/stats in my user application and caused java.lang.nullpointerexception

Tags: android, proc

I search the questions. It seems that they can read the /proc/net/xt_qtaguid/stats with out nullpointerexception.

But when I read this file it shut down the vm and report a java.lang.nullpointerexception

can anyone succeed to read this file?

update: Actualy, I can read this file through

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cat /proc/net/xt_qtaguid/stats")
```

or

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/proc/net/xt_qtaguid/stats"));
```

The nullpointerexception is cast due to my careless to use an uninitialized String[]

Comment: See https://github.com/facebook/network-connection-class/blob/master/connectionclass/src/main/java/com/facebook/network/connectionclass/QTagParser.java for an example. I believe this Android library uses this information to determine connectivity classes.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot read this file if you are not system. There is a reason these files are protected from the perspective of only being accesible by system uid.

Comment: can you give me some suggestions if I need read this information?